# Stop Kendo from changing the context of 'this' in event handlers

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, typescript

In the following event handler handling a Kendo DatePicker's changed event:

**EDIT**
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar-group">
    <div class="toolbar-item">
        <div class="toolbar-label">Approval Status: </div>
        <div class="toolbar-value">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:approvalStatus" readonly />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="toolbar-group">
    <div class="toolbar-item">
        <div class="toolbar-label">Authorised Date: </div>
        <div class="toolbar-value">
            <input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: authorisedDate, change: authorisedDateChanged }" placeholder="select authorised date" id="authorisedDate" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tradeGrid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: tradeRecords, filterable: true, pageable: { pageSize: 10 }}"></div>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the TypeScript/Javascript:

```
export class TradeAdminViewModel {

    public approvalStatus: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");

    public authorisedDate = ko.observable(new Date());

    public tradeRecords: any;

    constructor() {

        //make sure no records have been loaded yet - which shouldn't be possible
        if (this.tradeRecords == null) {

            //get the default records
            this.getTradeRecordsDefault();

        }    
    }

    authorisedDateChanged(e): void {
        console.log("date changed to: " + this.value());
        console.log("is equal: " + (e.sender === this));
    }

    getTradeRecordsDefault(): void {
        //get the root path for ajax calls
        var url: string = "/GetTradeRecordsDefault";

        //load the trade records
        $.getJSON(url)

            .done((result) => {

                //extract the records
                this.tradeRecords = ko.observableArray(result.TradeRecords);

                //add the approval status
                this.approvalStatus(result.TradeStatus);

                //apply all knockout bindings
                ko.applyBindings(this);
            })
            .fail((result) => {

                console.log("fail: " + result);

            });
    }
}
```

For the *getTradeRecordsDefault* event, the first line will write out **true** and the second will write out the new date selected.

This is fine, but there's no need to have both '**this**' and e.sender we could just use e.sender. Changing the context of 'this' is causing problems in a TypeScript/Knockout/Kendo environment where I need to update members of the ViewModel from the handler above which is in the same view model.

Is there a way to stop Kendo from changing the context of '**this**'?

Comment: You can use the old school solution: `var that = this;` in the parent function.

Comment: @Tarh not in A scenario where your Knockout ViewModel is handling the event because you need the 'this' context to be the ViewModel itself. TypeScript isn't helping the scenario much either

Comment: The convention in knockout is to capture the containing object's scope using var self=this; See 'a popular convention that simplifies things' here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Comment: @Jacques please add an example of code with the parent function of `authorisedDateChanged`.

Comment: @Tarh I've added a lot more code which should make it clearer.

Comment: OK. Actually, the problem comes from Kendo.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to stop Kendo from changing the context of 'this'?

The scope is dictated by JavaScript (not Kendo or TypeScript). When you call a method on a class, the scope of `this` will be the class. When you call a method as part of an event, the scope of `this` will be the event.

When you register the event handler, you can [preserve the context of `this` using an arrow function](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201504/Blog/TypeScript-Scope-Responsibility/).

For example, if you had the following event:

```
window.setTimeout(example.showText, 50);
```

You could preserve the scope of the `showText` method (i.e. make it so it was the class, not the event) using:

```
window.setTimeout(() => example.showText(), 50);
```

In cases where you want the event *and* the preservation of scope, you can use the following (I have used an onclick event to illustrate it):

```
document.body.onclick = (e) => example.showText(<HTMLElement>e.target);
```

You can even use an anonymous function to access both of the different contexts of `this`:

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    // this on the line below is the event.
    // this inside the showText method is the class.
    example.showText(this);
};
```

Comment: I actually think it is Kendo that is responsible for setting the context of this, because as you can see in the code e.sender is equal to this, which is the kendo widget in question whereas if what you're suggesting is correct it should have been the event object or not so?